# Python package or CLI tool outputting mutations of sequence with respect to reference

Tags: sequence-alignment, fasta, samtools, covid-19, sars-cov-2

I'm new to bioinformatics, and I'm looking for a tool that takes two FASTA files, one containing a reference, let's call it `A.fasta`, the other another sequence, let's call it `B.fasta`, and outputs just the mutations that `B` contains with respect to `A`.

I'm open as to the output format. Is there a standard for this?

Background: I'm trying to analyse Sars-CoV-2 sequences and identify mutations with respect to the reference. I've done a google search for a tool that does what I want to but couldn't find something straightaway. Is there no standard tool for this?

Comment: I would say parsimony, but thats just me

Answer (score 2):

If it's just a comparison of two sequences that you're looking for, then *diffseq* from the [emboss toolkit](http://emboss.sourceforge.net/what/) should be okay:

https://www.bioinformatics.nl/cgi-bin/emboss/diffseq

I think this tool requires the sequences to be oriented in the same direction. If you discover a *lot* more variants than you expect, try reverse-complementing one of the sequences.